# How do I use order by in HQL?

Tags: java, hql

I want to execute my HQL query like this:

```
Query queryPayment=sixSession.createQuery("from Payment where vcode=:p_Vcode or (Installment_Vcode=:installmentVcode and payment_date>:pdate) order byvcode."+order +"desc")
        .setParameter("p_Vcode", p_Vcode)
        .setParameter("installmentVcode", installmentVcode)
        .setParameter("pdate", pdate);
```

but it does not recognize `+order+`
I need the order by clause.

Comment: seems like you are missing a space before "desc", shold be " desc"

Answer (score 34, accepted):

appears you have to put the "order by" in the HSQL query, but with a space:

```
"from Payment where vcode=:p_Vcode or (Installment_Vcode=:installmentVcode and
payment_date>:pdate) order by vcode desc"
```

Comment: error is: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: order near line 1

Comment: I have tried this query:Query queryPayment=sixSession.createQuery("from Payment where vcode=:p_Vcode or (Installment_Vcode=:installmentVcode and payment_date>:pdate) order by vcode ." +order+" desc")
and the error is:Error invoking Action using Hibernate Core Session / Transaction injection
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: order near line 1, column 127 [from information.Payment where vcode=:p_Vcode or (Installment_Vcode=:installmentVcode and payment_date>:pdate) order by vcode order by vcode desc]
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxExc

Comment: try the query from my answer instead.